# How to get Data from InfluxDB API used HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, influxdb

Please somebody help me...

How to get InfluxDB v2 query Data...? used HttpClient.

I want to get query result data but no result just empty result

that image is I wanna data result.

[image]

this is my code, can you give me Resolutions( 1. post(URL, query) -> read data in one method solutions 2. post method, get method 2 method solutions)

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> RequestQuery()
{
    // client = new HttpClient();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    int refreshTime = 5;

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token " + token);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/csv");

    var fluxQuery = "from(bucket: \"DT_Object\")\n"
                   + "|> range(start: -7d)"
                   + "|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] ==\" NPC\")"
                   + "|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"NAME\"] == \"NPC\")"
                   + "|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"X\" or r[\"_field\"] == \"Y\" or r[\"_field\"] == \"Z\")"
                   + "|> aggregateWindow(every: "+ refreshTime + "s, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)"
                   + "|> yield(name: \"mean\")";

    var data = new StringContent(fluxQuery, Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.flux");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, data);
    Debug.Log(response);

    if (response.ReasonPhrase == "OK")
    {
        GetData1();
    }

    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    client.Dispose();

    return response;
}


 public string GetData1()
{
    string responseFromServer = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8086/api/v2/query?org=DT_navigator");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "text/csv";
        request.Timeout = 10 * 1000; // 10초
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token " + token);

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Debug.Log("Influx data : " + responseFromServer);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
    }

    return responseFromServer;
}
```

Comment: thank u modifiy code

Comment: What's not working with the code above? Do you get any error information in the response from the server?

Comment: first code RequestQuery method  status code 200, but  result is empty ...If I send it as a post, I want to receive the query result data like an image, but I don't know how to do it. and only used GetData1 Method  error is ( System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse.
)

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/api/#apiv2query-http-endpoint) state that the query method is `POST`, so I wouldn't expect `GET` to work (hence the 405 response code). I would suggest using the properties for `Authorization` and `Accept`, rather than trying to add them manually as you are. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you can make a succesful request with another tool, try using Telerik's Fiddler to view the raw requests as they are sent and compare the successful one with the C# one.

Comment: request.Timeout = 10 * 1000; // 10초
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Token " + token;
            request.Headers["Accept-Ranges"] = "bytes";  (405error)

Comment: request.'Accept' no attribute

Comment: Let's start from the top: why are you mixing `HttpClient` and `WebRequest`? `client.DefaultRequestHeaders` definitely has _properties_ (attributes exist in C#, and they are _not_ the same thing as properties) for `Accept` and `Authorization`.

Comment: I say in advance I learn 6mounts ago.... because HttpClient get code i not found .. I am wondering if I need to implement the post and get it separately to send the request and get that result value...?

Comment: This `+ "|> range(start: -7d)" + "|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] ==\" NPC\")"` will turn out without linebreak: `|> range(start: -7d)|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] ==\" NPC\")` . _Could_ that be an issue? (Not familiar with that DB and query language.)

Comment: Have you tried using a Client like this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/InfluxDB.Client/ instead of tinkering together the queries manually?

Comment: thank you Fildor I just found out why not. result is not empty that type is 'text/csv' so view like empty , now new 
Problem how to read response.content 'text/csv'...

Comment: I know that the library but can not used unity.. 
There is a conflict problem with Assembly